# Tapestry in Netbeans code completion for TML file not working

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9, tapestry

I am learning Apache Tapestry, but can't get Netbeans' autocomplete to work.

I am using namespace

```
xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_1_0.xsd"
```

But Netbean show error on mouse over **"No library found for this namespace"**.

And the auto complete feature won't work. I want Netbeans to show me list of Tapestry components when I type

```
<t:
```

I have also copied tapestry taglib from https://github.com/downloads/exanpe/tapestry-tldgen/t5.2.5.tld to my project's

```
src\META-INF
```

but doesn't work.

Though tried facelet-taglib from Netbeans bug page and it works fine, but not the custom one.

I also added the schema to DTD & XML of Netbeans but no joy.

Any idea on how I can get it to work?

kind regards,

Zerone